# How to get MIDDLE Data from a FILE

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have 10 records in a file and I don't need the first and the last line, I need data from 2 through 9 lines only.

Can anybody provide me solution on it?

Source file example:

```
SIDE,MTYPE,PAGENO,CONTIND,SUBACC,SIGN,DEAL QUANTITY,SECURITY,SOURCE SYSTEM,TODATE,SETTLEMENT DATE,REFERENCE 4,REFERENCE 2,TRADE DATE,ACCRUED INTEREST,ACCRUED INTEREST CURRENCY,XAMT1,XAMT2,XAMT3,XAMT4,XAMT5
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00107020052_CSA,107020052,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,200000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00115020036_CSA,115020036,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,220000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00301410097_CSA,301410097,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,226725,0,226725
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00030020088_CSA,30020088,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,250000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00106410075_CSA,106410075,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,260000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00116510010_CSA,116510010,6/12/2013,300000,USD,,0,250000,0,260000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00177020015_CSA,177020015,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,270000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00189110093_CSA,189110093,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,280000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,00272220015_CSA,272220015,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,10000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,SLAVE1,189110093,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,250000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,SLAVE2,272220015,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,1000
L,536,1,M,L_CAMS_COLATAGREEMENT,C,0,AGREEMENTS,CAMS_AGREEMENT,6/12/2013,6/12/2013,SLAVE3,301410097,6/12/2013,0,USD,,0,250000,0,200
```

Comment: There are no req. to remove the header , i just wanted to take all data except last line , pls suggest.

Comment: issue is i could not able to pass value from agg. to joiner , No linking visible when i join from exp. to joiner and agg. to joiner, however i have setup property as sorted output but still prob. are same, pls suggest.

Comment: Again, can you process the source file with a simple Bash script (called from the workflow) to get rid of the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in Informatica but I found the following answer on the web, hope it should be useful for you.

Step 1: You have to assign row numbers to each record. Generate the row numbers using the expression transformation. Create a DUMMY output port in the same expression transformation and assign 1 to that port. So that, the DUMMY output port always return 1 for each row.

Step 2: Pass the output of expression transformation to aggregator and do not specify any group by condition. Create an output port Ototalrecords in the aggregator and assign Ocount port to it. The aggregator will return the last row by default. The output of aggregator contains the DUMMY port which has value 1 and Ototal_records port which has the value of total number of records in the source.

Step 3: Pass the output of expression transformation, aggregator transformation to joiner transformation and join on the DUMMY port. In the joiner transformation check the property sorted input, then only you can connect both expression and aggregator to joiner transformation.

Step 4: In the last step use router transformation. In the router transformation create two output groups.
In the first group, the condition should be Ocount = 1 and connect the corresponding output group to table A. In the second group, the condition should be Ocount = Ototalrecords and connect the corresponding output group to table B. The output of default group should be connected to table C, which will contain all records except first & last.

Source: http://www.queryhome.com/47922/informatica-how-to-get-middle-data-from-a-file

Answer (score 0):

From informatica prospective, There are multiple way to do this. 
if data in flat file, the sqloverride would not work. you can create two pipe line, first line read from source and use aggregator get the count and assign to a mapping variable such v_total. second pipe line you use another variable v_count, initialize to 0 , call count function. create filter transformation, filter out  v_count=1 and (v_total-v_count)=1, the rest will be load to target.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a lot of code wasted making the mapping unnecessarilly complex when a simple unix command such as
head -9 (currentfilename) (newinputfilename)

Will do the job. Then all you need do is use the new file for your mapping (if you even need it anymore)

For a windows server equivalent see https://serverfault.com/questions/490841/how-to-display-the-first-n-lines-of-a-command-output-in-windows-the-equivalent